# mysql insert with select more columns

Tags: mysql

How can I insert lesser columns with select more columns? Something like below:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, COUNT(*) as total_count, column3
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 on table2.id = table3.fk_id
GROUP BY table2.column1
HAVING CASE WHEN column3 = 1 THEN total_count < 10
END
```

I want to insert only 2 columns, but I need the 3rd column for the HAVING condition. When I removed the column3 from select, it gives me

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'column3 ' in 'having clause'

.

Comment: Where do you want to insert these columns? The selected columns and those you want to insert are always a 1:1 match, but you can simply remove column3 from the `SELECT`

Comment: Why you would like to select more columns as you will insert? It makes no sence for me.

Comment: @DanielAlder, yea... that's the issue that I am having right now. I want to insert only 2 columns, but I need the 3rd column for the HAVING condition.

Comment: You can use columns in the HAVING which are not in the SELECT

Comment: (too many people commenting :-))

Comment: but I am getting unknown column in having clause

Comment: Its true that the column in GROUP BY need not be included in SELECT, but the column in HAVING has to be there in GROUP BY.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without looking at the schema, the only problem I see is in `GROUP BY` missing the column used in `HAVING` i.e., `column 3`.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (column1, column2)
SELECT column1, COUNT(*) as total_count, column3
FROM table2
INNER JOIN table3 on table2.id = table3.fk_id
GROUP BY table2.column1,table2.column3
HAVING CASE WHEN column3 = 1 THEN total_count < 10
END
```

without that included in the `GROUP BY`, you would get an error

> Unknown column 'column3 ' in 'having clause'

Comment: it worked! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any column in Where, Order by, having .... clauses without putting them in the SELECT statement.

Comment: When I removed column3 from SELECT, it gives me Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'column3 ' in 'having clause'

Comment: I think the error come from `CASE` condition,